# Factors to consider when Identifying minimum device recommendataions for my iOS app

Tags: ios, performance

I am trying to test an iOS application which is being used internally by our employees. Management procures devices for the employees who uses this app and they wanted us to test and identify the minimum device model in which our app runs without any performance issues.
Please note this is not for a compatibility testing where we see if apps are functional on different iOS devices. This is to see if the app is performing well on the device, since our app is memory intensive due to map layers. Please let me know what are the counters I need to capture in order to validate and identify the minimum recommended device?

we are capturing the time taken for each step using an XCUITest, and also the CPU times for some cpu intensive operations. However want to know which counters to consider when deciding across the devices.

Comment: I don't see how counters are going to help you.  You need to determine what is an acceptable level of performance/response time and then measure the time taken to perform various operations against that on various devices. Remember that on iOS the foreground app effectively has access to 100% of the device CPU and memory capacity